# How to show a HTML table without using getelementbyid and same?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm having this problem.
I have a HTML code which will show a table. The problem is I cannot use any id, name or whatever can be identify by getElementByID and same. I also have a dropdownlist have 2 value "Yes" and "No". I want to write a JavaScript or jsp tag which will show the table when I choose the value "Yes", and make it disappear completely when I choose "No".
Note: I cannot write a script make the page to reload
So how should I write the code? I'm thinking about using javescript like

```
<script>
function onchangedropdownlist
if(dropdownlistvalue = 1)
{
</script>
Code html table
<script>
}
</script>
```

or maybe I can use c:if. But i'm not sure how to use c:if with onchange.

Comment: You cannot use begining of condition `if(condition){` in one `<script>` tag and ending of condition `}` in another `<script>` tag like PHP echo. Post the table what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` to get the reference of your table and then use `.style.display` to `block`(show) or `none`(hide) your table.

***Demo Code***:

```js
function onchangedropdownlist(dropdownlistvalue) {
//if value is yes
  if (dropdownlistvalue == "yes") {
  //show table
    document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.display = "block"
  } else {
  //hide table
    document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      soemthing
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select onchange="onchangedropdownlist(this.value)">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this mean every table in the webpage will disappear as well when I choose No?

Comment: No only first table because i have use `[0]`  .Please refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to know more .

Comment: Thanks. 
One more question pls: Are there any tag only use to identify as a tagname and make no change to the UI?
For example I want to use the function above with 5 table, not only 1, so which tag should I use to combine all 5 table in 1 tag without changing the UI of the webpage?

Comment: Maybe using custom-attribute should work here check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) it will not change any thing in your html just add that attribute to your table .Also if you stuck anywhere let me know.

Comment: The [0] is count from the beginning of the webpage isn't it?

Comment: Yes first table in your dom.

Comment: thank you very much.
I want to learn more about this. What if i use toggle class use with onchange class, and whenever the value= yes the toggleclass change the css to display none?

Comment: yes you can do like that as well .Try that and see if that work or not.

Comment: Can you write a pseudo code for me pls? I dont know much about javascript :(((( Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224275/discussion-between-swati-and-hoang-truong).